# Localizing a naturally-formatted list of API data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization, formatting, internationalization

Say I've downloaded this list of data from an API:

```
[
    "Anita",
    "Jean",
    "Peter"
]
```

I'd like to list this data in a natural sentece format. For example, in US English, this string should be displayed to the user:

```
Anita, Jean, and Peter
```

However, if the user is Swedish for example, they should see this string:

```
Anita, Jean och Peter
```

Notice that the Oxford comma is missing, and Swedish uses a different word for "and", which is what a Swedish user would expect to see. How can I format this data in a natural-language way that would respect the user's locality? There can be a variable amount of data, not necessarily just 3 items. My instinct is to subclass `Formatter`/`NSFormatter`, but I'd like to build this in a way I can easily expand it to support languages that I don't speak, so I'm wondering if there's an iOS-standard or 3rd party formatter that I haven't been able to find in my searches

Comment: This data is encoded in the Unicode standard for [List Patterns](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-general.html#ListPatterns). Unfortunately, Apple doesn't expose this through Locale/NSLocale or any Formatter class that I've seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with iOS 13, Foundation has a [`ListFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/listformatter) type. According to your needs, you can use it in different ways to get a textual representation of your array.

---

The simplest way to use `ListFormatter` is to use its static [`localizedString(byJoining:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/listformatter/3130990-localizedstring) method. The following Swift 5.1 / iOS 13 Playground sample code shows how to implement this method in order to convert your array into a localized string representation:

```
import Foundation

let array = [
    "Anita",
    "Jean",
    "Peter"
]

let string = ListFormatter.localizedString(byJoining: array)
print(string) // prints: Anita, Jean, and Peter (for en_US locale)
```

---

As an alternative to `localizedString(byJoining:)`, you can create an instance of `ListFormatter` and use [`string(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/listformatter/3130992-string) method. This can be useful if you need to specify a locale for your textual representation:

```
import Foundation

let array = [
    "Anita",
    "Jean",
    "Peter"
]

let listFormatter = ListFormatter()
listFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR") // set only if necessary

let string = listFormatter.string(from: array)
print(String(describing: string)) // prints: Optional("Anita, Jean et Peter")
```

---

If needed, you can also set the [`itemFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/listformatter/3130988-itemformatter) property of your `ListFormatter` instance with a specialized formatter type:

```
import Foundation

let array = [
    55,
    112,
    8
]

let locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES") // set only if necessary

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = locale
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.spellOut

let listFormatter = ListFormatter()
listFormatter.locale = locale
listFormatter.itemFormatter = numberFormatter

let string = listFormatter.string(from: array)
print(String(describing: string)) // prints: Optional("cincuenta y cinco, ciento doce y ocho")
```

Answer (score 2):

In previous versions of iOS, this question remains unsolved and I'd still appreciate an answer if you have one. However, iOS 13 exposes [`NSListFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/listformatter), which can be used to do exactly this. For example:

Swift:

```
ListFormatter.localizedString(byJoining: ["Anita", "Jean", "Peter"])
```

Objective-C:

```
[NSListFormatter localizedStringByJoiningStrings:@[@"Anita", @"Jean", @"Peter"]];
```